# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Updating image with its path

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with a data repository pattern, I want to update other information and sometimes the image itself in my table. But when I am clicking on update button before I click on choose file the image is already deleted, and when I want to update other information but not image, also image is already deleted, that is why I have to upload image again.

This is my service code:

```
public async Task UpdateSlider(int id, bool isPashto, string img, string desc, bool notshow, int order, string intro)
{
    Slider slider = await _context.Sliders.FindAsync(id);
                
    var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/sliders/", slider.Img);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
    }

    slider.Img = img;
    slider.IsPastho = isPashto;
    slider.Desc = desc;
    slider.NotShow = notshow;
    slider.OrderShow = order;
    slider.Intro = intro;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And this is my controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSlider(int id)
{
    Slider slider = await _admin.GetSlider(id);

    AdminSliderViewModel viewModel = new AdminSliderViewModel()
            {
                Desc = slider.Desc,
                ImgName = slider.Img,
                NotShow = slider.NotShow,
                OrderShow = slider.OrderShow,
                IsPashto = slider.IsPastho,
                Intro = slider.Intro
            };

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSlider(AdminSliderViewModel viewModel, int id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Slider slider = await _admin.GetSlider(id);

        string sliderImg = slider.Img;

        if (viewModel.Img != null)
        {
            string filePath = "";
            viewModel.ImgName += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + viewModel.Img.FileName;
            filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/sliders/", viewModel.ImgName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                viewModel.Img.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            sliderImg = viewModel.ImgName;
        }

        await _admin.UpdateSlider(id, viewModel.IsPashto, sliderImg, viewModel.Desc, viewModel.NotShow, viewModel.OrderShow, viewModel.Intro);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ShowSliders));
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Please help me by refining my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get rid of these lines of code:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
}
```

Or, if these lines of code should only be executed when an image is uploaded, you could change it to the following:

```
if (img != slider.Img && System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
}
```